# SQL Server one column data as row and other one as column

Tags: sql, sql-server

Data within the actual table represents the intersection between two categories (for e.g a and b are categories). Data I have has multiple categories. In output table I need to show the intersection between such categories.

This is the actual table data. sample data

```
col1    Category    IntersectedCategory Count
----------------------------------------------
1       a           g               12
2       b           f               12
3       a           a               260
4       c           I               38
5       d           h               39
6       b           g               12
7       b           h               27
8       c           c               114
9       a           h               60
10      a           d               57
11      e           e               137
12      f           h               15
13      g           I               12
14      d           g               12
15      e           f               34
16      c           b               15
17      h           h               190
18      f           f               96
19      c           d               14
20      e           d               46
21      g           f               12
22      e           g               12
23      c           f               12
24      g           g               97
25      d           I               72
26      b           b               116
27      c           h               32
28      b           I               45
29      e           h               15
30      c           g               6
31      a           b               16
32      I           I               361
33      I           f               55
34      a           e               38
35      e           I               68
36      d           d               142
37      g           h               6
38      a           f               33
39      e           b               21
40      b           d               21
41      a           c               29
42      a           I               114
43      I           h               81
44      e           c               6
45      d           f               29
```

Expected Output:

```
list    a   b    
----------------
a       20  5
b       5   25
```

Comment: It is VERY confusing that both the first column and the seonc are named a,b. At least provide some column names from the actual table.

Comment: Save this question for 6 months and come back to it. I'm pretty sure that you'll not have any idea what did you ask for. In other words, try to write the questions in the way when the people who is not familiar with particular question would read it and understand.

Comment: Seems to me like you have broken something in the DB but i cant be sure as your question is so vague and pretty much means nothing, post some scripts so all the clever people on SO can tell whats up

Comment: He actually asks to pivot the 2nd and 3rd column based on the first one. It's just more suited to the puzzling stackexchange as it is....

Comment: My apologies for unclear explanation. Data within the actual table represents the intersection between two categories (for e.g a and b are categories). Data I have has multiple categories. In ouput table I need to show the intersection between such categories. Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

You can use Dynamic SQL for this.
Build a variable with the column names and then PIVOT on them.

**Example snippet:**

```
-- using a temporary table for demonstration purposes.
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TestTable') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #TestTable; 
CREATE TABLE #TestTable (col1 int identity(1,1) primary key, Category varchar(8), IntersectedCategory varchar(8), [Count] int);

-- Small set of sample data
insert into #TestTable (Category, IntersectedCategory, [Count]) values 
 ('a','a',20)
,('a','b',5)
,('b','a',5)
,('b','b',25)
;

-- Generating the column names
declare @cols varchar(max);

select @cols = concat(@cols+', ', quotename(IntersectedCategory)) 
from #TestTable 
group by IntersectedCategory
order by IntersectedCategory;

-- constructing the sql statement that uses a PIVOT
declare @DynSql varchar(max);
set @DynSql = 'select * 
from (select Category as list, IntersectedCategory as col, [Count] as total from #TestTable) as src
pivot (SUM(total) for col in ('+ @cols +')) as pvt 
order by list';

-- select @DynSql as DynSql; -- Just to check how the sql looks like

-- running the generated SQL statement
exec(@DynSql);
```

**Result:**

```
list a  b
---- -- --
a    20 5
b    5  25
```

Comment: Thanks @LukStorms. I have just updated the question with some more data. Can you please have a look again?

Comment: @ganeshdeshmukh With so many different values, I assume you have more use for a Dynamic SQL. Because else you'd have to hard-code each value.

Comment: can not hard code it. Values will be always dynamic.

Comment: @ganeshdeshmukh Ok, I've turned it into a dynamic sql with a pivot.

Comment: @ganeshdeshmukh Nice.  Guess you can accept it them. Btw, if you're altering the dynamic sql statement for your own purpose. (f.e. add a WHERE clause) then best to check first how the sql looks like before running it with exec.  That's why that select line is commented.

Comment: @ganeshdeshmukh Another thing, I used EXEC. But if you'll be using it with variables then better avoid the danger of SQL Injection and use [sp_executesql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql) with parameters.